# Is there any way for a fish function to read an optional input from pipe?

Tags: pipe, fish

Is there any way to read data that has been piped to the function, from inside the function, but only if there is any?
I tried it with cat like this:

```
function myPipe
    set -l pipe_input (cat -)
    echo $pipe_input # is never reached
end
echo test | myPipe
```

However, this results in the function stopping and waiting for pipe input, even if there actually was data piped to the function.

I would like fish to execute the rest of the function, even if there is no pipe input, so that I can handle the piped data.

Comment: You need to provide more context. What if stdin is attached to a file or fifo? Why do you need to do this? Note that in POSIX shells you would use `test -p 0` for this. However, as of fish 2.7 that doesn't work. I can't say whether that's ever been fixed in a newer release.

Answer (score 2):

You can test if stdin is connected to a pipe:

```fish
if isatty stdin
    set -l pipe_input ""     # not a pipe or redirection
else
    set -l pipe_input (cat -)
end
```

Ref: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#isatty

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out how to read **optional** input in a fish script:

The problem with `set -l pipe_input (cat /dev/stdin)` is that it will wait for input if the pipe '/dev/stdin' is empty, and therefore will stop execution at this point (with no pipe input).

- Therefore you simply have to iterate over the stream:

`cat /dev/stdin | while read line; set --append pipe_input "$line"; end`

- You can then easily go on and check if the variable (an array/list) has content:

  `if test (count $pipe_input) -gt 0; echo "got pipe input: $pipe_input"; else echo "empty pipe"; end`